# Linq query 'and' 'or' operators

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have written a LINQ query with 'or' condition and 'and' but its not working well.

```
from x in db.fotoes.Where(x => x.uid == NewsId && 
x.ukat == 'fukat1' || x.ukat == 'fukat2')
```

i cant figure out why its not working,can anybody help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "not working well". What output are you expecting and what output are you actually getting?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just try like this, you need to use parentheses to group your conditions:

```
from x in db.fotoes.Where(x => x.uid == NewsId && 
(x.ukat == 'fukat1' || x.ukat == 'fukat2'))
```

Answer (score 9):

Group your conditions by adding parentheses:

```
from x in db.fotoes.Where(x => (x.uid == NewsId) && 
                         (x.ukat == 'fukat1' || x.ukat == 'fukat2'))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from x in db.fotoes.Where(x => x.uid == NewsId && (
x.ukat == 'fukat1' || x.ukat == 'fukat2'))
```

Is it what you're trying to do? You can group a set of conditions by having them inside parenthesis.